# error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for '.svn'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm

I have an angular 2 app under SVN. When i want to start it, using

```
npm start
```

I'm getting this error:

> error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for '.svn'.

By making a copy of the app's folder and removing all svn files inside it, the application starts well, but i would like to work on the folder under SVN.

**Is there any way to get rid of this error and to make it work in a folder under SVN?**

I have tried:

1. adding a `.npmignore` file in the app's folder, having this content: ".svn"
2. specify the exclude in tsconfig.json like this:

   ```
   {
       "compilerOptions": {
           "target": "es5",
           "module": "commonjs",
           "moduleResolution": "node",
           "sourceMap": true,
           "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
           "experimentalDecorators": true,
           "removeComments": false,
           "noImplicitAny": false
       },
      "exclude": [".svn"]
   }
   ```
3. to find a "compilerOptions": option

but all in vain :(

Thanks.

Comment: You probably got an `.snv` file left in your folder.

Comment: Eran, i have all the svn files in that folder. The question is: how to make "npm start" work with the svn files in there. Thanks